# Can't find Administration icon on Oracle 11g Express Edition

Tags: windows-7, oracle-11g

I am referring the Steps to Create i2b2 Database Users from following [documentation](http://community.i2b2.org/wiki/display/getstarted/3.3.1+Create+User+Accounts+in+Oracle). They have in their screenshot an Administration Icon which can be seen as below :

[image]

However, the Admin console of my Oracle 11g looks like below:

[image]

I don't see Administration icon and wondering where should I find it in order to proceed forward with creating Database Users as mentioned in the 4th step of the documentation.

I have Windows 7 64 bit on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you've shown IS the administrator page, as evidenced by the caption in the corner:

[image: Admin Caption]

If you look at the right-hand column, the link to create a user is right there:

[image: User Controls]

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up creating users using the command line. And when I click on Find a User and try to search for the users I created using the username, I don't see any one of them getting listed over there. Could you tell me what could be the problem?